# Access redis on host from inside docker container?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker, redis

I have a host server that I'm deploying a dockerized Rails app on. The redis on the host server is not dockerized.

I'm trying to figure out how I can access the redis pub/sub on the host server from within the dockerized Rails app. The redis on the host server is configured to only be accessible from localhost.

Is there anyway for me to forward the pub/sub messages into the docker container? If it makes it easier, I don't really need to publish messages, only subcribe to read them.

Comment: It should be possible as long as your Rails app container's network settings allow that - refer to docker's docs on setting up the network.

Comment: I think it's tricky because the redis on the host server isn't running in a Docker container, and it's only accessible from localhost.

Comment: what ip have you tried to direct the container to? does using the host ip not work?

Comment: I tried directing it to the host IP, but I recently found out that the redis is only configured to listen on localhost, so it didn't work.

Comment: may i suggest killing the redis server and launching a server under docker, with the proper port exposed?

Comment: I can't edit anything on the server because that will require others to who use the app (which is an addon) to do the same. Is there a way for me to pass it in through a volume? There has to be a way to do it because the redis and docker container (rails app) are both running on the same host server.

Comment: Try to set your app to connect db on IP 172.17.0.1. I think it's a default docker interface and you should be able to connect.